# GtkSharp 3 File Dialogs

Tags: c#, gtk, gtk#

I'm using the following to show a GTK file chooser dialog in an app that otherwise doesn't use GTK for anything else.

```
Gtk.FileChooserDialog fc =
    new Gtk.FileChooserDialog(openParams.Title,
        null,
        FileChooserAction.Open,
        "Cancel", ResponseType.Cancel,
        "Open", ResponseType.Accept);
```

This is basically straight from the example at http://docs.go-mono.com/index.aspx?link=T%3aGtk.FileChooserDialog. It works fine using gtk-sharp 2.0, but when I switch to gtk-sharp 3.0 I get this:

```
(mono:30587): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: cannot register existing type 'GtkWidget'
(mono:30587): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: cannot add class private field to invalid type '<invalid>'
(mono:30587): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: cannot add private field to invalid (non-instantiatable) type '<invalid>'
(mono:30587): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_type_add_interface_static: assertion 'G_TYPE_IS_INSTANTIATABLE (instance_type)' failed
(mono:30587): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: cannot register existing type 'GtkBuildable'
(mono:30587): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_type_interface_add_prerequisite: assertion 'G_TYPE_IS_INTERFACE (interface_type)' failed
(mono:30587): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_once_init_leave: assertion 'result != 0' failed
(mono:30587): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_type_add_interface_static: assertion 'G_TYPE_IS_INSTANTIATABLE (instance_type)' failed
(mono:30587): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_type_register_static: assertion 'parent_type > 0' failed
(mono:30587): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: cannot add private field to invalid (non-instantiatable) type '<invalid>'
```

The searching I did indicates that the "cannot register existing type" thing happens when mixing library versions. I made sure that my assembly references point to version 3.0 of gtk and all its associated libraries (atk, gio, glib), but its still happening. How can I figure out whats going wrong?

Comment: Something is still loading GTK+ 2 and calling `gtk_widget_get_type()` on it. You might need to look deeper into what you are importing or your project settings; the assembly references aren't enough, it seems. I wouldn't personally know what's causing it; sorry. Also are you sure it only happens when running that specific line of code? Or does it happen with the rest of your program as well?

Comment: I stepped through it and its definitely happening on that line. Not sure what else could be pulling in GTK2, since no other part of the project uses GTK. Heres the file in question, if that helps. https://github.com/unlimitedbacon/agg-sharp/blob/master/GtkFileDialogs/FileDialogPlugin.cs

Comment: What is `MatterHackers.Agg.UI` pulling in then?

Comment: A lot of things, including `System.Windows.Forms` and `OpenTK`. From running with `MONO_LOG_LEVEL=debug`, it seems like winforms is pulling in `libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0`. I think that must be the problem then. If winforms really relies on gtk2, then that would cause the conflict.

Comment: I wouldn't know how to fix that; then; sorry. Good luck!